# How do I find the interface of Rhythmbox?

Tags: software-recommendation, default-programs

I opened a mp3, thus started Rhythmbox and then minimized the UI. Now I can't find a way to find the UI anymore, it's not in the taskbar nor can I access it from alt-tab. What can I do?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? Unity? KDE?

Comment: Just installed from 13.04, haven't done anything to desktop environment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the top launcher icon, which is an application search function (it looks like the Ubuntu logo on a grey background). From there type in 'Rhythmbox' and you can access it from there.

Also, I would suggest dragging the icon on to the taskbar for speedy access when doing this in future.

:)

Comment: Thanks! It worked just like that. It's quite weird for me though, as opening other programs will keep them in the taskbar, but not Rhythmbox. Is it a special kind of programme? I think the developers should put more effort in making the system user friendly.